# jQuery Slide menu hover action

Tags: jquery, menu, hover, slide

ok thing is like this, I got **2 divs**, one is my **navigation**,
the other got the same number of li tags with almost same id's as my navigation, those li tags contains a **graphic** that suppose to **slide** when hover the nav.
Let me explain...

this is **my nav**

```
<ul id="navInside">
  <li><a id="nInicio" href="index.php" >Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a id="nHistoria" href="history.php" >Historia</a></li>
  <li><a id="nQuienes" href="aboutus.php" >Quienes somos</a></li>
```

this is what **should move**

```
<ul id="navSlides">
  <li id="SnInicio"></li>
  <li id="SnHistoria"></li>
  <li id="SnQuienes"></li>
```

This is the **jQuery** code i got now....

```
    $('#navInside li').hover(function (){
    $("#S" + this.id).animate({top: '0px'}, 500)}, function (){
    $("#S" + this.id).animate({top: '-70px'}, 500, 'swing');} 
);
```

Can you help me get the **right selector** for this to work?

I been stuck for days... 
Thank you

Comment: little things like hunting for an ID that's one level below where you think it is will get you, but Nick's Nailed it.  Sometimes I use the "jQuery Selectors" Chrome extension to make sure I am addressing the right element if I get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` is on the anchor, not the `<li>` (which `this` refers to) so your hover should be:

```
$('#navInside li a').hover(function (){
  $("#S" + this.id).animate({top: '0px'}, 500);
}, function (){
  $("#S" + this.id).animate({top: '-70px'}, 500, 'swing');
});
```

Or, use the code you have and move the `id` up to the `<li>`, like this:

```
<ul id="navInside">
  <li id="nInicio"><a href="index.php" >Inicio</a></li>
  <li id="nHistoria"><a href="history.php" >Historia</a></li>
  <li id="nQuienes"><a href="aboutus.php" >Quienes somos</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, I am unclear as to what $("#S" + this.id) is?  I don't see id="S" anywhere else in the html...

Comment: Hi, That is because there are to <ul> one with id="navInside", and another with id="navSlides", when hover the navInside <li>'s, then move the slide (in the slide you can use a color box or image or icons to move ^^ really cool... you can check out the final result in www.conelectricas.com